# Cakephp 3 App::paths() gone, what do I use now?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

In CakePHP 2.X, you could have files in multiple places and cakephp would iterate over the available places until it found the file.  An example in CakePHP 2.X would look something like this.

```
App::build(array(
    'Controller' => array(
        ROOT.DS.'Customize'.DS.'Path2'.DS.'Controller'.DS,
        ROOT.DS.APP_DIR.DS.'Controller'.DS
        )
));
```

How does CakePHP 3 accomplish this?  For example if I install a plugin with composer and I want to overwrite a controller file only within that plugin from my app, how would I go about doing that, and where are the paths that CakePHP 3 iterates through defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer in the CakePHP 3.0 book : http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html#additional-class-paths

Using your composer.json file. It looks in the first path first, and the second path second.

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": ["./path1/path1/src", "src"]
    }
},
```